# Iframe website is reloading when i attempt to log in

Tags: html, iframe, src

I am trying to make a website that I can use to quickly navigate around all my school's websites.
But I have run into an issue, when I sign in, instead of taking me to my account it just reloads the website. ie, when I put in my login details, it reloads the page instead of taking me to the next page.
I am very new to this, (my first website) so I'm not too sure why.

This is the line of code:

`<iframe src="https://tc-vic.compass.education/" width="100%" height="1080"></iframe>`

Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention, it works fine in Internet Explorer, but no other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

probobly the schools webserver can see that the page is loaded inside an iframe and not direct in a browser.
That could make a difference for functional and security reasons.

Comment: Its possible, but it works in IE, but nothing else. I think it may be an issue with the browser?